# R in SQL Server: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: sql-server, r

I am trying to port some of my working R scripts to SQL Server. I have the following R code:

```
titanic <- read.csv(titanicUri, header = TRUE)
titanic <- titanic[complete.cases(titanic),]
titanic$AgeGroup <- cut(titanic$Age, c(0,13,100), labels=c("Young","Old"))
```

I created a table in SQL Server and imported the data. When I attempt to implement the 'cut' function like this:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script    
      @language = N'R'    
    , @script = N' 
        titanic <- InputDataSet;
        titanic <- titanic[complete.cases(titanic),];
        titanic$AgeGroup <- cut(titanic$Age, c(0,13,100), labels=c("Young","Old"));
        titanic <- data.frame(titanic);
        OutputDataSet <- titanic;
        '    
    , @input_data_1 = N' SELECT Name FROM Titanic;'    
    WITH RESULT SETS (([PassengerName] varchar(Max)));
```

I am getting this error (the complete.cases works fine)

> Error in titanic$Age : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>
> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 11
> A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
>
> Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> An external script error occurred:  Error in titanic$Age : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors Calls:
> source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> cut
>
> Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information. Error in
> eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for
> more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
> .Call Execution halted
>
> Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified 1
> result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run
> time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `InputDataSet` contain only a single column?  If so, then probably your problem is that it was converted from a data.frame to a vector when you said `titanic[complete.cases(titanic),]`  Try: `titanic[complete.cases(titanic), , drop = FALSE]`

Comment: If my guess is right, it doesn't have anything to do with the fact that you're using SQL Server, it's just that `read.csv(titanicUri, header = TRUE)` returns a data.frame with multiple columns, whereas `InputDataSet` has one column (I'm guessing).  It's a bit of a gotcha that R treats these two cases differently.

Comment: Indeed, @TimGoodman, OP is only selecting one column in input data set `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimGoodman comments, your input dataset is one column due to specified `SELECT` query. Simply expand column listing to have *Age* available:

```
@input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM Titanic;'
```

Consider too specifying output dataset. See helpful [mssqltips.com guide](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4126/sql-server-2016-r-services-executing-r-code-in-sql-server/).

```
@output_data_1_name = N'titanic'
```